# New Azure data disk does not appear when running lsblk from virtual machine's cli

Tags: azure, azure-virtual-machine, azure-managed-disk

I am attempting to create and attach a new data disk to an Azure linux VM per these instructions: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/attach-disk-portal

Azure Portal reported that the disk was created and attached to my VM successfully, and I can see it listed as a data disk under "Disks" for that VM in Azure Portal. However, when I run `lsblk` from the VM's command line, as instructed under "Find the disk" in the documentation, the new disk does not appear in the listing. Therefore I can't proceed in setting up the disk.

How can I get the disk to show up in `lsblk`, or at least begin to diagnose why it didn't? The VM is running Ubuntu 20.04, in case that matters.

For what it's worth, immediately before this, I executed the same process to add a different data disk to a different VM and it went very smoothly, so there seems to be some particular problem with this VM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been in touch with Azure support and they've diagnosed (through some back-end method) that the storage module (`hv_storvsc`) on the virtual machine is down. They have stated that the only solution is to reboot the virtual machine.

Answer (score 1):

If the VM was running when you added the disk, you need to rescan for the new disk. Rebooting will work, but you can rescan without rebooting.

If the sg3-utils package is installed, you can use rescan-scsi-bus.sh to rescan. If not you can use the following:

```
for h in $(ls /sys/class/scsi_host); do
    echo '- - -' > /sys/class/scsi_host/$h/scan
done
```

***For more information Refer this Document*** : [***Virtual Hard Disk is added, but not showing using lsblk -d command***](https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/virtual-hard-disk-is-added-but-not-showing-using-lsblk-d-command-4175645367/)